# Linked/chained MagicSuggest dropdowns?

Tags: php, jquery, magicsuggest

I am trying to build a set of linked/chained multiselect boxes using MagicSuggest and a php query.  So, first I build a MagicSuggest box with a function for when ms1 is changed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var ms1 = $('#ms1').magicSuggest({
    data: 'datams1.php',
    displayField: 'name' });

$(ms1).on('selectionchange', function(event, combo, selection){
    run(selection);});
});
```

Then I build a new MagicSuggest box by running a php query that returns a json object:

```
function run(country) {
$.getJSON("query.php", { id: country[0].id}, callbackFuncWithData );
}

function callbackFuncWithData(region) {
var ms2 = $('#ms2').magicSuggest({
    data: region,
    displayField: 'name'
    });
}
```

This works once I make an initial selection, but does not update if I change the selection.  I have checked and within my "callbackFuncWithData" I am producing an updated "region" json object.  So it might just be that I need to refresh/reload my #ms2 object.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to force an refresh of the MagicSuggest data?
2. Is there a better/cleaner/more efficient way to use the results of one MagicSuggest box to query and return the data for a second, linked MagicSuggest box?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. use setData() method to dynamically set the data when needed.
2. you can always use a library like angular to bind the component properties together.

Answer (score 0):

This code makes 2 linked combos with the same data, but one of them shows the "name" field and the other one shows the "name1" filed.

```
function reflectSelection(ms1, ms2){
var val = parseInt(ms1.getValue());
var val1 = parseInt(ms2.getValue());
if(!isNaN(val)){
  if(val != val1){
    ms2.clear(true);
    ms2.setSelection(ms1.getSelection());
  }
}
else
{
  ms2.clear(true);
  }

 }

 var msName = $('#ms-onselectionchange').magicSuggest({
    maxSelectionRenderer: function(){ return ''; },
    useTabKey: true,
    noSuggestionText: '',
    strictSuggest: true,
    maxSelection: 1,
    allowFreeEntries: false,
    placeholder : '',
    data: [{'id':0, 'name':'Paris', 'name1':'Paris5'}, {'id':1, 'name':'New York', 'name1':'New York5'}],
  });

var msName1 = $('#ms-onselectionchange1').magicSuggest({
    maxSelectionRenderer: function(){ return ''; },
    useTabKey: true,
    noSuggestionText: '',
    displayField: 'name1',
    strictSuggest: true,
    maxSelection: 1,
    allowFreeEntries: false,
    placeholder : '',
    data: [{'id':0, 'name':'Paris', 'name1':'Paris5'}, {'id':1, 'name':'New York', 'name1':'New York5'}],
  });
  $(msName).on('selectionchange', function(e,m){
   reflectSelection(msName, msName1);

  });

  $(msName1).on('selectionchange', function(e,m){
    reflectSelection(msName1, msName);
   });
```